# Calling Python from Java through scripting engine (jython)?

Tags: java, python, jython, javax.script

I'm trying to call Jython from a Java 6 application using `javax.script`:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class jythonEx
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws ScriptException
    {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine pyEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("python");
        try {
            pyEngine.eval("print \"Python - Hello, world!\"");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

This is causing a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jythonEx.main(jythonEx.java:12)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

*Edit:*

Thanks for the responses!  I added jython.jar to the classpath and it runs properly:

```
java -cp "./;jython.jar" jythonEx
```

Comment: Which one is line 12? pyEngine.eval("");?

Comment: @ilikeorangutans: Yes, that's the line 12.

Comment: That's right.  I'm presuming that the ScriptEngineManager can't find the python engine, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong that would cause that...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to register your engine first.

From: [ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#getEngineByName%28java.lang.String%29):

> *[...] first searches for a ScriptEngineFactory that has been registered as a handle [...] Returns null if no such factory was found*

The user guide says [to use it with JSR-223](http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#using-jsr-223) you have to:

> *As of Jython 2.5.1 an implementation of JSR 223 is bundled in jython.jar. Simply add jython to your CLASSPATH and ask for the python script engine.*

<strike>Did you do that already?</strike>

**EDIT**
About your comment: I think you should open a new question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: No, I never did that, thanks!  I've used JavaScript through javax.script before without doing anything, so I clearly missed that step.  Let me try it now...

Comment: @griffin Great!, probably that will do. Let us know if it work would you?

Comment: @griffin I'm glad!! good luck with that python + java integration ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to register a ScriptEngineFactory for'python'